# View Eslint errors in a file

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, eslint, typescript-eslint

I have started using EsLint in my angular project to make better readable code. So far everything is going well but one thing I am still searching for is how to export the errors/warnings to an excel/txt file or view them in the browser in a `.html` format which I can share with my team members.
I have used sonarqube in a few of my projects and they provide a good UI to view.

Can anyone give any suggestions?

**.eslintrc.json**

```
{
  "root": true,
  "ignorePatterns": [
    "projects/**/*"
  ],
  "overrides": [{
      "files": [
        "*.ts"
      ],
      "parserOptions": {
        "project": ["**/tsconfig.json"],
        "createDefaultProgram": true
      },
      "extends": [
        "plugin:@angular-eslint/recommended",
        "plugin:@angular-eslint/template/process-inline-templates"
      ],
      "plugins": ["unused-imports"],
      "rules": {
        "@angular-eslint/component-selector": [
          "error",
          {
            "prefix": "otp",
            "style": "kebab-case",
            "type": "element"
          }
        ],
        "@angular-eslint/directive-selector": [
          "error",
          {
            "prefix": "otp",
            "style": "camelCase",
            "type": "attribute"
          }
        ],
        "sort-imports": [
          "error",
          {
            "ignoreDeclarationSort": true
          }
        ],
        "no-unused-vars": "off",
        "unused-imports/no-unused-imports": "error",
        "unused-imports/no-unused-vars": [
          "warn",
          {
            "vars": "all",
            "varsIgnorePattern": "^_",
            "args": "after-used",
            "argsIgnorePattern": "^_"
          }
        ]
      }
    },
    {
      "files": [
        "*.html"
      ],
      "extends": [
        "plugin:@angular-eslint/template/recommended"
      ],
      "rules": {}
    }
  ]
}
```

**package.json**

```
{
  "name": "otp",
  "author": "",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve --proxy-config proxy.conf.json",
    "build": "ng build",
    "compdoc": "npx compodoc -p tsconfig.doc.json --port 8081 --serve",
    "test": "ng test",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "e2e": "ng e2e"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "~12.2.16",
    "@angular/cdk": "^12.2.13",
    "@angular/common": "~12.2.16",
    "@angular/compiler": "~12.2.16",
    "@angular/core": "~12.2.16",
    "@angular/forms": "~12.2.16",
    "@angular/localize": "^12.2.16",
    "@angular/material": "^12.2.13",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "~12.2.16",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "~12.2.16",
    "@angular/router": "~12.2.16",
    "@ng-select/ng-select": "^6.1.0",
    "@ngxs/store": "^3.7.2",
    "ngx-material-timepicker": "^5.5.3",
    "rxjs": "~6.5.4",
    "tslib": "^2.0.0",
    "zone.js": "~0.11.4"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "^12.2.18",
    "@angular-eslint/builder": "12.7.0",
    "@angular-eslint/eslint-plugin": "12.7.0",
    "@angular-eslint/eslint-plugin-template": "12.7.0",
    "@angular-eslint/schematics": "12.7.0",
    "@angular-eslint/template-parser": "12.7.0",
    "@angular/cli": "~12.2.18",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "~12.2.16",
    "@angular/language-service": "~12.2.16",
    "@compodoc/compodoc": "^1.1.11",
    "@ngxs/devtools-plugin": "^3.7.2",
    "@ngxs/logger-plugin": "^3.7.2",
    "@types/jasmine": "~3.6.0",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "~2.0.3",
    "@types/node": "^12.11.1",
    "@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin": "4.28.2",
    "@typescript-eslint/parser": "4.28.2",
    "eslint": "^7.26.0",
    "eslint-plugin-unused-imports": "^2.0.0",
    "jasmine-core": "~3.6.0",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~5.0.0",
    "karma": "~6.4.1",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~3.1.0",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "~3.0.2",
    "karma-jasmine": "~4.0.0",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^1.5.0",
    "protractor": "~7.0.0",
    "ts-node": "~8.3.0",
    "typescript": "~4.3.5"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

[image]When specified, the given format is output to the console.
If you’d like to save that output into a file, you can do so on the command line like so:

This saves the output into the *results.txt* file

```
npx eslint -f compact file.js > results.txt
```

***For html format*** :

```
npx eslint -f html file.js > results.html
```

Comment: how this can be done in angular? I've written like ```ng lint -f html file.js > results.html``` but throwing error as it cannot find file.js

Comment: @Avishek you have to replace the "file.js" with the  individual component file of which you need the error log in html format or whatever. Also, you have use  to "eslint" not "ng lint" as you have mentioned you are using eslint. ping me if you need further help.

Comment: ```ng lint``` is using eslint it's configured in angular.json & in my angular.json its stated which files to pick for linting

Comment: @Avishek can you please share the config file in the post?

Comment: I've updated the question with the config details.